# There are thousands of JavaScript at the beginning of the .html file when output by RMarkdown

Tags: javascript, html, r, r-markdown, markdown

We used RMarkdown for static .html pages, but there is javascript at the beginning of each document consisting of thousands of lines when we checked the source codes (line 17 to line 27 in the first figure), even for a simple "hello world" webpage. Is there any way to eliminate this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VS6g.jpg)

````
    ---
    title: "Untitled"
    output: html_document
    ---

    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
    ```
    ## R Markdown

    This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.
````

And the output .html source code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="generator" content="pandoc" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" />




<title>Untitled</title>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="generator" content="pandoc" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" />

<title>Untitled</title>

<script src="data:application/x-javascript;base64,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
```

I truncated the code, they are very long. Please check the first figure, and hope this could help.

In the meantime, I also used another computer to generate the .html file with the same code. It showed the difference. I pasted 2 parts of the scripts here.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqTqc.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUhmt.jpg)

Are the javascript in these two files have the same function? And why they are so different? I guess they are the same and the first version is the compressed version of the expanded one, right?

I also tried the method provided [How to render HTML from RMarkdown without javascript in output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370306/how-to-render-html-from-rmarkdown-without-javascript-in-output). The format will be removed. Thus, is there any way to remove the scripts but keep the format?

Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: From [R Markdown: The Definitive Guide](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#document-dependencies): *"By default, R Markdown produces standalone HTML files with no external dependencies, using data: URIs to incorporate the contents of linked scripts, stylesheets, images, and videos. This means you can share or publish the file just like you share Office documents or PDFs."* and subsequent paragraphs. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @MrFlick, Oh, I see. But this manipulation would remove all the format I set in the markdown.

Comment: Also relevant: [Reduce file size of R Markdown HTML output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41237664/reduce-file-size-of-r-markdown-html-output)